# Remove only first line break

Tags: regex, sed, line-breaks

I have quite a few files where I want to get rid of a particular line break. The line always begins with "Title:" and so I tried the following command:

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/^Title: \n\t*/Title:/g' {} \;
```

But from what I understand, `sed` only handles one line at a time, and so the above won't work. Is there a way to remove a line break (in multiple files), but only if the line begins with some string?

Comment: The line **begins** with "Title:" or is that the **entire** line? In your attempt the *entire line* consists of exactly "Title:" followed by one space *and nothing else*. Please clarify. Also, you didn't mention removing tabs, but your attempt looks for zero or more tabs after the newline; what's with that? If you need to handle those tabs, say so in your text question, not just in the code.

Comment: A couple more questions: Can you have two consecutive lines that begin with "Title:"? Can the **last line** in your whole thing begin with "Title:"? If so, in both cases, what is the desired handling?

Comment: @mathguy I simplified the regex above to make it a little more understandable and to show the main idea. That's why I said "begins with" above. And no, it's generally one of the first 10 lines in the file that starts with "Title"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU `sed`, you may use

```
sed '/^Title: $/{N;s/.*\n\t*\(.*\)/Title:\1/}'
```

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/1pfc4o)

**Details**

- `/^Title: $/` - finds a line with contents equal to `Title:`
- `{N;s/.*\n\t*\(.*\)/Title:\1/}` - a block executed once the line above is found:

  - `N` - gets the next line and appends a newline and that line to the pattern space
  - `s/.*\n\t*\(.*\)/Title:\1/` - replaces the pattern space (that holds two lines now)  using the `.*\n\t*\(.*\)` pattern that matches

    - `.*` - any 0+ chars
    - `\n\t*` - a newline and 0+ tabs
    - `\(.*\)` - Capturing group 1: any 0+ chars
    - `/Title:\1/` - replacement pattern, `Title:` and the value inside Group 1.

Comment: Missing the `-E` flag? I believe capture groups and backreferences require it.

Comment: No, it is a POSIX BRE expression.

Comment: In a Free BSD sed, try `sed -e '/^Title: $/ {' -e N -e 's/.*\n\t*\(.*\)/Title:\1/' -e '}'`

Comment: Oh, OK, right. My memory is failing me - I read the POSIX standard once, and I thought I knew what is BRE and what is ERE, but clearly there are bugs in my memory. Thx!

Comment: Why do you not need to close off with a `/` at the end? So why is this wrong: `sed '/^Title: $/{N;s/.*\n\t*\(.*\)/Title:\1/}/'` ?

Comment: There should be no `/` at the end, there is a  block.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
sed '/^Title:/{N;s/[[:blank:]]*\n[[:blank:]]*/ /}'
```

This will look for any line that begins with the string "Title:". It will append a newline and the next line in the input. Then it will search for a newline character, optionally preceded and/or followed by any number (zero or more) of blank characters - meaning space or tab - and it will replace this whole thing with a single space.

This assumes that the "Title:" line may also include other text (on the same line) and that should be preserved. That is my understanding of your question, from what you said in words (it doesn't match your attempt though).

You may need special handling if your input may contain two consecutive lines that begin with "Title:" (this solution will join them into a single line), and if the very last line begins with "Title:" (this solution will just leave it alone - unless, of course, the line right above it also began with "Title:").

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -Ez 's/((^|\n)Title:) \n\t*/\1/g' file
```

Slurp the file into memory using the [`-z`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Command_002dLine-Options) option.

Allow for extended regexp by using the `-E` option.

If the first or any subsequent line begins with `Title:` followed by a newline and zero or more tabs, remove the trio of a space followed by newline followed by zero or more tabs.

This may reduce the file into a further matching state, so a loop may be needed:

```
sed -Ez ':a;s/((^|\n)Title:) \n\t*/\1/g;ta' file
```